# update chef environment attr from recipe

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Is it possible to update chef environment attribute from chef recipe?
When am trying to use the following

```
node['apps']['current_version'] = node['apps']['new_version']
```

am getting exception

> Node attributes are read-only when you do not specify which precedence level to set. To set an attribute use code like `` `node.default["key"] = "value"' ``

But even with node.default["key"] approach it's not updating env attributes.

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious what you need to change from the error message...

Comment: it's not updating the environment attributes that way unfortunately

Comment: What do you mean by "environment attributes". Have you seen the attribute precedence model?

Comment: I mean attributes which is assigned to env

Comment: How would you expect that it is automagically saved to the environment? It is only saved for the one node with the corresponding precedence level. In order to modify an environment's attributes, you explicitly have to modify the environment (only possible for admins in the open source version of Chef Server).